# Facebook location button through Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, messenger

I'm currently developing a facebook messenger bot using dialogflow.
I need to send the location button, on the facebook custom payload what i have to write?

```
   {
      "facebook": {
        "attachment": {
          "type": "",
          "payload": {}
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried many thing but i can't figure it out
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide more information about you are trying to do and how to make it easier for others to help out. 

Please include:
 - Where exactly are you adding the snippet you've written here?
 - Explain what you expect to see.
 - Explain what you actually see instead.
 - You say that you have tried many things, but please describe what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

To request a Facebook Messengers user's location your custom payload should look like this:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "text": "give me your location please",
    "quick_replies": [
      {
        "content_type": "location"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Source: https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/platform-events#facebook_location